R Complex Date Related and Cumulative Value Summation in R
I have data that looks like the following:
df <- tibble(
  date= seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2022-02-01"), by = "month"),
  val1 = c(105, 105, 105, 125, 125, 125, 125, 132, 132, 132, 135, 150, 150, 150),
  val2 = c(100, 100, 100, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 150, 150, 150),
  diff = val1-val2)

I am trying to produce the following:
output <- tibble(
  date= seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2022-02-01"), by = "month"),
  val1 = c(105, 105, 105, 125, 125, 125, 125, 132, 132, 132, 135, 150, 150, 150),
  val2 = c(100, 100, 100, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 150, 150, 150),
  diff = val1-val2,
  diff_calc = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 22, 22, 22))

Where diff_calc is the cumulative sum of the previous unique values in diff, where the summing occurs starting where diff = 0 for the previous diff value, and is replicated until diff is 0, and the previous unique diff values are again cumulatively summed.
I have tried different combinations of lags and joins, but am really struggling here. Thanks!

Is it unique diff values that should be summed, or unique (val1, val2) sets? E.g., what if 2021-10-01 had val1 = 133 and val2 = 126 (diff would still be 7)?

On line 8, how do you get diff_calc = 5?

@MelissaKey, diff_calc updates only when diff == 0.

@jblood94 it is unique diff values

This is very similar to @jblood94's answer, but might be a little simpler
df |> 
  mutate(
    diff_calc = cummax(cumsum(diff * !duplicated(diff)) * (diff == 0)),
  )




Amazing this is great. I accepted this answer to your point about it being a slightly simpler solution. Thank you so much!

This assumes that the values included in the cumsum are the unique values from the beginning of df, rather than the unique values in the previous non-zero block (as in my solution). Which is correct isn't clear from the question, so it really depends on what the OP intended.

I've realized there's a problem with this solution, which is that it sums consecutive discrepancies when the discrepancy starts as 0. Not sure if there's a quick for that.

can you provide a reproducible example showing where you're still having issues?

df$diff_calc <- with(df, cummax(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(diff) != 0)*diff)*(diff == 0 & c(0, diff[-nrow(df)]) != 0)))
df
#> # A tibble: 14 × 5
#>    date        val1  val2  diff diff_calc
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 2021-01-01   105   100     5         0
#>  2 2021-02-01   105   100     5         0
#>  3 2021-03-01   105   100     5         0
#>  4 2021-04-01   125   125     0         5
#>  5 2021-05-01   125   125     0         5
#>  6 2021-06-01   125   125     0         5
#>  7 2021-07-01   125   125     0         5
#>  8 2021-08-01   132   125     7         5
#>  9 2021-09-01   132   125     7         5
#> 10 2021-10-01   132   125     7         5
#> 11 2021-11-01   135   125    10         5
#> 12 2021-12-01   150   150     0        22
#> 13 2022-01-01   150   150     0        22
#> 14 2022-02-01   150   150     0        22


It appears this works, but definitely open to better solutions.
library(timetk)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(diff != 0) %>% 
  group_by(diff) %>%
  top_n(1, date) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  
  mutate(
    diff_sum=cumsum(diff),
    date1=lead(date),
    date_diff=interval(date, date1) %/% months(1),
    date2 = date %+time% "1 month")%>% 
  
  filter(date_diff !=1 | is.na(date_diff)) %>%
  select(date2, diff_sum) %>%
  
  pad_by_time(
    .date_var = date2,
    .by = "month", 
    .start_date = "2021-01-01", 
    .end_date = "2022-02-01") %>% 
  
  fill(diff_sum, .direction = "down")

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("date" = "date2"))

